# bluetooth does not work linux ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I tried a lot of commands from many websites nothing helps

systemctl | grep -i blue output:

```
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d14-1\x2d14:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device     loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0    
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                            loaded active     plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0                                     
  bluetooth.service                                                                      loaded active     running   Bluetooth service                                                         
  bluetooth.target                                                                       loaded active     active    Bluetooth
```

dmesg | grep -i blue output:

```
[    3.871950] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.871975] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.871978] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.871979] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.871983] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.151677] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.151687] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.151696] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

sudo rfkill

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

sudo dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn

```
86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
MMIO Stale Data CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/processor_mmio_stale_data.html for more details.
 #5 #6 #7
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.BAT1], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS13._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS13._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TFN1 (20210331/dspkginit-438)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TFN1 (20210331/dspkginit-438)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TFN1 (20210331/dspkginit-438)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TFN1 (20210331/dspkginit-438)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TFN1 (20210331/dspkginit-438)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TFN1 (20210331/dspkginit-438)
hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:02)
acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:02)
usb: port power management may be unreliable
r8169 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
systemd-journald[302]: File /var/log/journal/4cc96ea5ece04bb8a630e8058f8dd817/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
ACPI Warning: \_SB.IETM._ART: Found unexpected NULL package element (20210331/nsrepair-186)
ACPI Warning: \_SB.IETM._ART: Expected return object of type Reference (20210331/nspredef-249)
_ART package 0 is invalid, ignored
_ART package 1 is invalid, ignored
_ART package 2 is invalid, ignored
mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
MXM: GUID detected in BIOS
ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20210331/nsarguments-61)
ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20210331/nsarguments-61)
mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Firmware init done
kauditd_printk_skb: 60 callbacks suppressed
systemd-journald[302]: File /var/log/journal/4cc96ea5ece04bb8a630e8058f8dd817/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
```

[image]

Comment: Try running a Live version of Ubuntu 22.04 or Fedora 36 and see if either of them works. Your issue could be down to the old kernel in your Ubuntu. `mt7921e` used to have serious troubles with some kernel versions, e.g. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=273641

Comment: BTW, here's an answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368717/mediatek-mt7921-bluetooth-not-detected

Comment: FYI I get the ACPI errors using `journalctl -b`, and I think it is because I disabled sleep states in the BIOS on my Dell XPS-15 9570.  First two error lines for me are: "kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)" and "kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)" . Cheers